# SAS Passing Multiple User Input Values to Macro Variable

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am using SAS Web Report Viewer where I have an interface from which end users can select the multiple values as an input to a macro variable. However, when I check the SAS Logs I see that only the first input value is passed on to the macro variable. How can I get all the values passed on to the macro variable? (And if possible separate the values using '|' as a delimiter). For example here I am trying to pass 'Discount_Logility' and 'Discount_EDD' as the inputs to the variable 'list_string' (I want the variable to dynamically take in more inputs depending on how many the user passes).

```
%put &list_string;
```

Here is the SAS Log

```
>>> SAS Macro Variables:

 LIST_STRING=Discount_Logility
 LIST_STRING0=2
 LIST_STRING1=Discount_Logility
 LIST_STRING2=Discount_EDD
 LIST_STRING_COUNT=2
```

But here we can see that the macro variable 'list_string' takes only the first input, 'Discount_Logility'

```
21        +%put &list_string;
Discount_Logility
```

How can value of 'list_string' variable be list_string = Discount_Logility | Discount_EDD OR whatever be the best way to pass in the multiple inputs to the list_string variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAS passes each one into its own macro variable. Note these three entries in the log:

```
LIST_STRING1=Discount_Logility
LIST_STRING2=Discount_EDD
LIST_STRING_COUNT=2
```

You can use `LIST_STRING_COUNT` and iterate over all the selections.

```
%macro convert_to_list;
    %global list_string;
  
    %let list_string = &list_string1;

    %do i = 2 %to &list_string_count.;
        %let list_string = &list_string.|&&list_string&i.;
    %end;
%mend;

%convert_to_list;

%put &list_string;
```

```
Discount_Logility|Discount_EDD
```

Comment: If I want to pass the values as either Discount_Logility,Discount_EDD (i.e. comma as a separator) or if I want to use '| ' (i.e. line and space) as a separator then what should I do? 
%let list_string = &list_string.,&&list_string&i.;

Comment: You can generate the macro variable with commas instead of pipes by just changing the pipe to a comma in the %LET statement in the posted answer.  But working with a macro variable that has commas in it is going to be much trickier in some situations.  Like trying to pass the value into a macro call since the commas will be seen by the macro processor as separators.  It might introduce the need to add macro quoting.

Comment: @Tom I tried using the pipe operator but get this error
ERROR: Format name | not found or the width and/or decimal specified for the format used are out of range.
ERROR: Required operator not found in expression: %sysfunc(countw(&list),|))..this does tie to the earlier question I asked that you had answered...  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76740784/sas-running-multiple-macros-based-on-variable-value-passed-through-as-a-list

Comment: You ended the COUNTW() function call before you could pass it the delimiter argument .  Instead you add an extra argument to the %SYSFUNC() function call, which expects a FORMAT name.  `%sysfunc(countw(&list,|))`  But why are you counting them again when you started with the count to begin with?

Comment: Yes you're right. Don't need to count it again. I used 
%do i=1 %to &list_string_count.;
     %let buriza=%scan(&list,&i,|);

and this seems to work for now. Thank you.